# What is the meaning of using COMM_WORLD or COMM_SELF to instantiate a TS, DMDA, Vec, etc

Tags: openmpi, petsc

I'm looking at several examples from PETSc and petsc4py and looking at the PDF user manual of PETSc. The manual states:

> For those not familiar with MPI, acommunicatoris a way of indicating a collection of processes that will be involved together in a calculation or communication. Communicators have the variable type `MPI_Comm`. In most cases users can employ the communicator `PETSC_COMM_WORLD` to indicate all processes in a given run and `PETSC_COMM_SELF` to indicate a single process.

I believe I understand that statement, but I'm unsure of the real consequences of actually using these communicators are. I'm unsure of what really happens when you do `TSCreate(PETSC_COMM_WORLD,...)` vs `TSCreate(PETSC_COMM_SELF,...)` or likewise for a distributed array. If you created a `DMDA` with `PETSC_COMM_SELF`, does this maybe mean that the `DM` object won't really be distributed across multiple processes? Or if you create a `TS` with `PETSC_COMM_SELF` and a `DM` with `PETSC_COMM_WORLD`, does this mean the solver can't actually access ghost nodes? Does it effect the results of `DMCreateLocalVector` and `DMCreateGlobalVector`?

Answer (score 1):

The communicator for a solver decides which processes participate in the solver operations. For example, a TS with PETSC_COMM_SELF would run independently on each process, whereas one with PETSC_COMM_WORLD would evolve a single system across all processes. If you are using a DM with the solver, the communicators must be congruent.